# Callback to add boxplots in Tensorboard / cannot use .numpy() in on_batch_end

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I want to add in Tensorboard a boxplot of the final values returned by the model during training. Even though I have enforced eager execution I can't make this work because I can't access model output values in `on_batch_end` methods.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, GlobalAvgPool2D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback


class CustomCallback(Callback):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.output_values = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.output_values += [self.model.output.numpy()]

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        output_values = np.concatenate(self.output_values).flatten()
        plt.boxplot(output_values)
        canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(plt.gcf())
        canvas.draw()
        s, (width, height) = canvas.print_to_buffer()
        image = np.fromstring(s, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))
        tf.summary.image(self.name, image)


model = Sequential([
    Input((224, 224, 3)),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3)),
    GlobalAvgPool2D(),
    Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])


X = np.random.rand(100, 224, 224, 3)
y = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)

tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, y, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])

# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: A Keras model is not internally eager. It's like a static function, you need to have a custom training loop to get that value or call predict_on_batch. The first will perform better.

Comment: I used to have sort of a hack in tf1.13 using kwargs in `model.compile` to pass in `fetches` a `tf.assign(callback.tensor, model.output)` but I can't make this work now.